# RDLC: how to merge rows dynamically

Tags: c#, rdlc

How to merge rows in RDLC vertically? I've read some answers that its not possible but any work around?
I've also tried the solution specified [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0fcbb23a-55cc-4134-b1dc-baf314513940/merge-row-cell-on-table-in-rdlc?forum=vsreportcontrols) but its not working.

I wish to achieve like **Result** column below:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If its belongs in same group like header, detail or footer you must be allowed to merge cell, but if its in different groups than not possible.

Comment: yes, its the same column header. if its possible, how?

Comment: can u add screenshot?